# Setting a dynamic formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to run the below code.

```
Sub TabRef()
crag = ActiveCell.Value
crag = Replace(Replace(Replace(crag, " ", "_"), "-", "_"), ",", "_")
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
MsgBox (crag)
MsgBox ("=" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Route Name]]")
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Route Name]]"
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Stars]]/" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Route Name]]"
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Rating 3]]/" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Route Name]]"

End Sub
```

I will run this once and it will work perfectly fine, but I will run it again and get "Run time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error" I do not understand why it will work with one cell but not another, when the tables and columns in those tables are defined.

Comment: Which line gives you the error ?

Comment: ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Route Name]]"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in what the original value of the active cells is. You cannot use text in a formula without wrapping it in quotes or Excel will try to determine it as a 'named range' or 'list object'. This line,

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & crag & "[[#Totals],[Route Name]]"
```

... will fail with `Run time error: 1004` if the cell's value is text. Change it to:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "'=" & Chr(34) & crag & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & "[[#Totals],[Route Name]]"
```

That should be sufficient to put the commented formula into the cell. Go back into the worksheet and adjust the formula to a working one with your list object table references. When you have a working formula, adjust the VBA to accommodate the new formula.

I apologize for not being more precise but your list object table references have admittedly stumped me.

You may also wish to use `Debug.Print` instead of `MsgBox` and follow the results in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).

Comment: I am trying to have it refer to an object, however I just figured out that there was an extra space after the text, causing the formula to not point to the object. Trying the code you gave me helped me figure this out. Thank you